# curvature as as function of tangential angle

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am reading a paper where the authors have defined the curvature $\kappa$ as 
\begin{align}
\kappa = \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}
\end{align}
where $\phi(r)$ is the angle that the tangent makes with the horizontal plane and $r$ is the distance to the origin $O$, see the figure below. However, in another paper, I find a similar but different definition of curvature which is given by
\begin{align}
\kappa = \dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r} \left(r^2 \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \right) = r\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} + 2\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}
\end{align}

Using the standard definition of curvature given by
\begin{align}
\kappa = \dfrac{\dfrac{d^2 y}{d x^2}}{\left[1 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 \right]^{3/2}}
\end{align}
I have tried to derive the curvature as a function of the tangent angle, but so far have been unsuccessful. If anyone could help or provide a reference I would appreciate it.

[image: interface curvature]

Comment: The definition in the first section should be $\kappa=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}$ where $s$ is arc length not direct line distance

Comment: @DavidQuinn I am aware of that definition for curvature, but don't think thats what the authors were intending. Is it possible to write the curvature in terms of the radial distance $r$?